# importing data "BLOB" type from one DB to another in oracle

Tags: oracle, import, blob

i am facing problem, while importing data from one DB to another. The problem is with when i want to import a table which contains BLOB type data. Can any one please help me, how to import BLOB type data or how to move BLOB type data from one DB to another.

Please help me.

Comment: If it were me, I'd write some SQL to read it all out of one database and store it into the second database, one at a time. But that assumes you can have both databases reachable and responding to the one application.

Comment: i am using pl/sql developer, i wrote one select statement on the table with BLOB datatype, and i took the sql script from it . the issue is that the insert script what pl/sql gave me contains "<BLOB>" value in the column with BLOB datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to simply move a table from one Oracle DB to another? Use [Oracle Data Pump.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_dp.htm#i436481)

Copy data from one Oracle DB into another Oracle DB, perhaps into a different table structure? Use PL/SQL with [DBMS_LOB package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#BABDDFDH).

Also, have a look at the [Large Objects Applilcation Developer's Guide.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/toc.htm)